# Can shortcuts be accessed through python script 2.8?

Tags: python

Can shortcuts be accessed through python script 2.8? I'm referring here at box select, tweak, cursor.
I know that is not best practice but I just curious how to access those left window buttons.

Comment: Hi. What do you mean by "access" the shortcuts? Are you just trying to activate the tools or do you want to do something with the shortcut, like edit it?

Comment: @RayMairlot to activate/deactivate them.